# How to make Gtk.Box fill all the available space?

Tags: gtk3, vala

The layout looks like on the image below: two boxes encapsulated in vertical box with a specified width. Single big box is positioned on the right. The big box should fill all the available space, however it is not happening despite `Gtk.Align.FILL` property set.

[image: The Layout]

Please ignore the "Utilization" box.

```
        cpu_utilization_chart = new Chart (cpu.core_list.size);
        cpu_frequency_chart = new Chart (1);
        cpu_temperature_chart = new Chart (1);

        var smol_charts_container = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
        smol_charts_container.add (cpu_frequency_chart);
        smol_charts_container.add (cpu_temperature_chart);

        var big_box = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0);
        big_box.add (smol_charts_container);
        big_box.add (cpu_utilization_chart);

        attach (title_grid, 0, 0, 1, 1);
        attach (grid_usage_labels(), 0, 1, 1, 1);
        attach (big_box, 0, 1, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I ditched `Gtk.Grid` and replaced it with a `Gtk.Box`.

```
        pack_end (cpu_utilization_chart, true, true, 0);
        pack_end(smol_charts_container, false, false, 0);
```

And also did `smol_charts_container.hexpand = false;`

[image]